# What is a class level lock in java

Tags: java, multithreading

What is a class level lock. Can you please explain with an example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java class level lock vs. object level lock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718148/java-class-level-lock-vs-object-level-lock)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to a synchronization lock. If you are unfamiliar with synchronization it is a means to prevent the same code being run by two different threads at the same time. In java synchronization is done with Object locks:

```
Object lock = new Object();

public void doSomething(){
  ...
  synchronized(lock){
    //something dangerous
  }
  ...
}
```

In this code it is guaranteed only one thread can do something dangerous at a given time, and it will complete everything in the synchronized block before another thread may start running the same code. I am guessing what you are referring to as a "class level lock" is the implicit lock on synchronized method:

```
public synchronized void somethingDangerous(){...}
```

Here again only one thread can execute the method at any given time and will always finish before another thread may begin executing the code. This is equivalent to a synchronized block on "this":

```
public void somethingDangerous(){
  synchronized(this){
    //something dangerous
  }
}
```

Now this lock isn't actually on the class, but rather on a single instance (i.e. not all clocks, but only your clock). If you want a true "class level lock" (which would typically be done in a static method), then you need to synchronize on something independent of any instances. For example:

```
public class Clock{
  private static Object CLASS_LOCK = new Object();

  public static void doSomething(){
    ...
    synchronized(CLASS_LOCK){
      //something dangerous to all clocks, not just yours
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

again there is an implicit lock for static methods:

```
public class Clock{
  public static synchronized void somethingDangerous(){}
}
```

which is the equivalent of locking on the class object:

```
public class Clock{
  public static void somethingDangerous(){
    synchronized(Clock.class){
      //do something dangerous
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use the `synchronized` keyword on a `static` method, the object whose monitor is used for the lock is the class object, i.e. the one represented by the literal `MyClass.class`. It is also used implicitly to syncronize during the initialization of the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

It's called an intrinsic lock, and every object has one. We need to separate two things, and it's not entirely clear what you mean by "class level lock".

Here's an example:

```
class Locker {
    public void x() {
        lock(this) { ... }
    }

    public void y() {
        lock(this) { ... }
    }
}
```

As you can see, both method uses "this" as a lock target - this way you can guarantee that they won't be ever interleaved. You can achieve this implicitly with the synchronization keyword:

```
class Locker {
    public synchronized void x() {
        ...
    }

    public synchronized void y() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The two examples are the same on the bytecode level.

However, by class lock, you *could* mean a lock on the actual class object - not an instance of it. That's how synchronized static methods work.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.coderanch.com/t/232571/Threads-Synchronization/java/class-level-lock-object-level#1082419

synchronised on a static method :)

Answer (score 0):

*Class level lock* and *instance level lock* both are different, mutually exclusive. Both don’t interfere each other lock status. If one instance of a class has already got locked by a thread then another thread can’t get lock for that instance until unless lock is freed by first thread.

Same behaviour is there for *class level lock*.

But if a thread acquires *Class level lock* then another thread can acquire lock on one of its instance. Both can work parallel.