# Java class level lock vs. object level lock

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

If a thread T1 enters a method m1 by obtaining the class level lock, does this mean another thread T2 cannot run a different method m2 by obtaining the object level lock?

Comment: The Class Level Lock is for static method of your class.suppose one class is there MyThread which is having static m1() here MtThread thread got an class level lock for accessing m1() because m1() is static but in other case if MyThread class having static or instace level m2() and any other thread wants to execute for m2() that will allow for m2().

Answer (score 58):

No, it doesn't mean that.  The "class level lock" is just a regular lock on a different object, namely `SomeClass.class`.  The "object level lock" locks on `this`.

**Edit:** Just to make sure I'm following your understanding of the terminology, you're wondering if m1 and m2 can be run concurrently as they are defined below:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public synchronized static void m1() {
       //do something
    }

    public synchronized void m2() {
       //do something
    }
}
```

And the answer is yes, m1 and m2 can be run concurrently.  It is functionally equivalent to this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static void m1() {
        synchronized (SomeClass.class) {
           //do something
        }
    }
    public void m2() {
        synchronized (this) {
           //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Since they are synchronizing on completely different objects, they are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: what if both the methods are declared static? I believe in that case, both will become mutually exclusive, is that correct?

Comment: @buch11: That's correct, it would be as if both were doing `synchronized (SomeClass.class) {...}`, and barring any complex classloading scenarios, this will be the same object in both cases.  Technically, classloading allows you to have two separate "loadings" of the same class, and you could run static synchronized methods in such different classes in parallel.  But barring that funkiness, it's mutually exclusive.

Comment: You might wonder what happens when a static synchronized method is invoked, since a static method is associated with a class, not an object. In this case, the thread acquires the intrinsic lock for the Class object associated with the class. **Thus access to class's static fields is controlled by a lock that's distinct from the lock for any instance of the class.**

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

Comment: what if both m1 and m2 are trying to edit the value of a static member ? two different threads entering m1 and m2 at sametime would not create a problem ?

Comment: @ChetanGowda: If the operation you're performing on the static member is not itself threadsafe, then yes this would be a synchronization problem, as the operation could happen from `m1` and `m2` concurrently.

Comment: @MarkPeters : So is this a problem with Java, or is this something they expect developers to avoid ? I am disturbed that such a possibility exists. Using static members in non static method seems like a fair usecase.

Comment: @ChetanGowda: I don't understand where you think the problem is here.  If you need two sections of code to be mutually exclusive, you need both to synchronize on the same mutex.  If `m2` needs to mutually exclusive of `m1`, i.e. on `SomeClass.class`'s mutex, then synchronize on that explicitly in `m1`, i.e. `synchronized (SomeClass.class) {` as shown above.  Or depending on the situation, use another primitive such as `ReentrantLock`, or an `AtomicReference`, or a threadsafe collection, etc, etc.

Answer (score 37):

## Object level locking:

Object level locking is mechanism when you want to synchronize a non-static method or non-static code block such that only one thread will be able to execute the code block on given instance of the class. This should always be done to make instance level data thread safe. This can be done as below :

```
public class DemoClass 
{ 
  public synchronized void demoMethod(){} 
} 

or 

public class DemoClass 
{ 
  public void demoMethod(){ 
  synchronized (this) 
  { 
   //other thread safe code 
  } 
 } 
} 

or 

public class DemoClass 
{ 
  private final Object lock = new Object(); 
  public void demoMethod(){ 
  synchronized (lock) 
 { 
  //other thread safe code 
 } 
}
```

---

## Class level locking:

Class level locking prevents multiple threads to enter in synchronized block in any of all available instances on runtime. This means if in runtime there are 100 instances of DemoClass, then only one thread will be able to execute demoMethod() in any one of instance at a time, and all other instances will be locked for other threads. This should always be done to make static data thread safe.

```
public class DemoClass 
{ 
  public synchronized static void demoMethod(){} 
} 

or 

public class DemoClass 
{ 
  public void demoMethod(){ 
  synchronized (DemoClass.class) 
  { 
   //other thread safe code 
  } 
 } 
} 

or 

public class DemoClass 
{ 
 private final static Object lock = new Object(); 
 public void demoMethod(){ 
 synchronized (lock) 
  { 
   //other thread safe code 
  } 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 11):

> Example to understand Object and Class level locks in Java

**1) Object Level lock example**

```
package com.test;

public class Foo implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Lock();
    }
    public void Lock() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        synchronized(this) {
            System.out.println("in block " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("in block " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " end");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo b1 = new Foo();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(b1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(b1);             
        Foo b2 = new Foo();
        Thread t3 = new Thread(b2);             
        t1.setName("t1");
        t2.setName("t2");
        t3.setName("t3");             
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

> output:

```
    t1
    t3
    t2
    in block t3
    in block t1
    in block t3 end
    in block t1 end
    in block t2
```

Note that t3 will not block when threads t1 and t2 block. Because the lock is placed on this object and thread **t3 has different this object** than thread t1,t2

**2) Class Level lock example**

The code in object level lock, only Foo.class is added in synchronized block.
All the threads are getting created using object of Foo class will get blocked.

```
package com.test;    
public class Foo implements Runnable {        
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Lock();
    }

    public void Lock() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        synchronized(Foo.class) {
            System.out.println("in block " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println("in block " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " end");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo b1 = new Foo();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(b1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(b1);             
        Foo b2 = new Foo();
        Thread t3 = new Thread(b2);             
        t1.setName("t1");
        t2.setName("t2");
        t3.setName("t3");             
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

> output:

```
t1
t3
in block t1
in block t1 end
t2
in block t3
in block t3 end
in block t2
in block t2 end
```

Synchronized block is going to be executed for the same thread.

Comment: So, does this mean when the class level lock is placed only one thread will execute the synchronized block at one time irrespective of 'this' object?

Comment: Yes. For class level locking only one thread will execute the static synchronized block. Other threads can execute non-static synchronized blocks.

Answer (score 6):

In java there are two types of locks:

1. Class Level
2. Object Level

In case of Static methods the lock is always checked on class
     but in case of instance methods the lock is always checked on object.

**Example:**

`show1()` is *non static* and `show()` is *static*.
Now, `show()` is called by class name (or by object) and 
`show1()` is called by object, then both methods can accessed
simultaneously by two threads.

```
class Shared{
    static int x;
    static synchronized void show(String s,int a){
        x=a;
        System.out.println("Starting in method "+s+" "+x);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){ }
        System.out.println("Ending from method "+s+" "+x);
    }
    synchronized void show1(String s,int a){
        x=a;
        System.out.println("Starting show1 "+s);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(Exception e){ }
        System.out.println("Ending from show1 "+s);
    }
}
class CustomThread extends Thread{
    Shared s;
    public CustomThread(Shared s,String str){
        super(str);
        this.s=s;
        start();
    }
    public void run(){
        Shared.show(Thread.currentThread().getName(),10);
    }
}
class CustomThread1 extends Thread{
    Shared s;
    public CustomThread1(Shared s,String str){
        super(str);
        this.s=s;
        start();
    }
    public void run(){
        s.show1(Thread.currentThread().getName(),20);
    }
}
public class RunSync {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shared sh=new Shared();
        CustomThread t1=new CustomThread(sh,"one");
        CustomThread1 t2=new CustomThread1(sh,"two");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Starting in method one 10
Starting show1 two
Ending from method one 20
Ending from show1 two
```

Answer (score 4):

Nope, both can execute concurrently.
1.When class level lock is applied on one method **synchronized(SomeClass.class)** and on other method object level lock is applied **synchronized(this)** then, both can execute at same time.

only when class level lock is applied on both methods then there is no concurrent execution.

Reason being: for class, jvm creates object for java.lang.Class, i.e. in short everything in java is object. So, when class level lock is applied on 2 methods, common lock is applied on class object and every object has single lock so, every thread waits, but when different instance is used to invoke the 2nd method and instance level lock is applied at that time, this object lock is applied which is different from class object lock and so concurrent execution is possible.

Comment: I have a doubt here when the different instance is used to invoke the 2nd method and class level lock is present then 2nd instance is going to wait or he can update ?

Answer (score 3):

Class level lock is achieved by keyword "Static Synchronized,where as object level is achieved only by synchronized keyword.
Object level lock is achieved to restrict same object to operate through different thread,where as class level lock is achieved to restrict any object to operate.

Answer (score 2):

Class level lock and instance level lock both are different. Both don’t interfere each other lock status. If one instance of a class has already got locked by a thread then another thread can’t get lock for that instance until unless lock is freed by first thread.
Same behaviour is there for class level lock.

But if a thread acquires Class level lock then another thread can acquire lock on one of its instance. Both can work parallel.`

```
package lock;

class LockA implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (LockA.class) {
            System.out.println("Class");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
public class TestClassVsInstanceLock {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LockA a = new LockA();
        final LockA b = new LockA();
        try {
            Thread t = new Thread(a);
            Thread t1 = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (b) {
                        System.out.println("Instance 1"+ currentThread().currentThread().holdsLock(b));
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
            t1.start();
            synchronized (a) {
                System.out.println("Instance2");
                Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`

This will print : -
Instance2
Class
Instance 1true

All will get printed instantly without any pause.

Answer (score 1):

Different ways of class level locking:
1)
public class DemoClass {

```
public static synchronized void demoMethod(){
    //dosomething
}
```

}

2)

public class DemoClass {

```
public void demoMethod(){

    synchronized(DemoClass.class){
        //dosomething
    } 
}
```

}

3)

public class DemoClass {

```
private final static Object lock = new Object(); 
public void demoMethod(){

    synchronized(lock){
        //dosomething
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

> It’s possible that both static synchronized and non static synchronized method can run simultaneously or concurrently because they lock on different object.

[Courtesy](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/08/thread-synchronization-object-level-locking-and-class-level-locking/)

Answer (score 0):

**Instance Level Locking**, Only single thread is allowed to execute at a time using instance level locking.

```
 public class Refactor implements Runnable {
        private Object obj;

        public Refactor(Object obj)
        {
            this.obj = obj;
        }

        public void run() {

            if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Test1")) {
                test1();
            } else {
                test2();
            }

        }

        public void test1() {
            synchronized (obj) {
                System.out.println("Test1");
            }
        }

        public synchronized void test2() {
            synchronized (obj) {
                System.out.println("Test2");
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Object obj = new Object();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Refactor(obj));
            t1.setName("Test1");
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Refactor(obj));
            t2.setName("Test2");
            t2.start();
        }

    }
```

**Class Level Locking**, Only single thread is allowed to execute at a time using class level locking.

```
public class Refactor implements Runnable {
    private Object obj;

    public Refactor(Object obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void run() {

        if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Test1")) {
            test1();
        } else {
            test2();
        }

    }

    public static void test1() {
        synchronized (Refactor.class) {
            System.out.println("Test1");
        }
    }

    public static synchronized void test2() {
        synchronized (Refactor.class) {
            System.out.println("Test2");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Refactor(obj));
        t1.setName("Test1");
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Refactor(obj));
        t2.setName("Test2");
        t2.start();
    }

}
```