# Implicit locking - what actually gets locked

Tags: java, multithreading, static, synchronization

My Question is nearly equivalent to this [What is a class level lock in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462104/what-is-a-class-level-lock-in-java)

But this is a follow up question.

Instance level locking works by getting lock on associated monitor of instance/object, but in case of class level locking who plays a role of monitor? How implicit locking works?

Thanking you

Comment: To think of locking as "class level" or "object level" will only distract your attention away from what locking really means.  When you write `synchronized` you should think about which object your code synchronizes on, and what it means in your program for a thread to synchronize on that object.  When you add `synchronized` as a declaration specifier on a static method of class Foo, that's the same as writing `synchronized (Foo.class) { ... }` in the method body.  It's entirely up to you to decide what a thread is allowed to do when synchronized on Foo.class.

Comment: No, there was no doubt about what locking really means. My doubt was what actually gets locked in case of class level locking. Thank you for ur time.

Comment: Sorry,  Sometimes I assume too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, to get a *class* representation in an object-oriented context, the `Class` class was created.

So, when you get a class-level lock, in the static context, you are getting the associated monitor of the `Class` object instance for that "class name".

```
public class com.buck.Foo {

}
```

for example would have a "class level lock" on something that was type equivalent to

```
Class<com.buck.Foo> clazz = Foo.class;
```

The wording may be odd, but pay close attention to the capitalization.

```
class is a keyword

Class is a type that represents a "class instance"

Foo.class is a convention to refer to an instance which has the type "Class<Foo>"

clazz is a variable which can accept the instance of type "Class<Foo>"
```

Comment: so this object gets initialized at classloader level ? if yes then can v initialize it more than once?

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes, it gets initialized withing the classloader.  Within a class loader, it is typically not initialized twice (the class loader will reuse the `Class` instance); however, it is easily initialized twice in two class loaders, or by other means (typically involving serialization or reflection).  Some of the older __Singleton Pattern__ techniques had problems with multiple "singleton" classes due to not considering all of the ways classes can be loaded.  Look at those "singleton implementation problems" if you are curious.