# Object Lock and Class Level Lock

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I had attended an Interview and they raised me a question.It was

**"At what context do you decide that you should go for Object Lock/Class Level lock" ?**

My reply was:

If want to apply the synchronization concept on static method you need to go for Class Level Lock else one should go for Object Lock.

Is there any better answer for this?

Comment: Yet another poorly phrased interview question. 'At what context' indeed. Meaningless.

Comment: ok, Was my answer correct or was there something more which I should have added.

Comment: @user2900314 - Actually you could go for *any kind of lock* in both static and non-static contexts. Class level locks and Instance level locks are used by *default*. So, fundamentally, the question itself is flawed.

Comment: @user2900314 - Also, I would not *recommend* using the term *method* because you can synchronize in *static initializers* and *instance level initializers*. :)

Comment: Yes, I missed that point. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I'd have said:  I find "Object level lock" and "class level lock" to be unhelpful names that obscure what's really going on.  The important questions are, _what is the invariant that needs protection?_ and _where is the lock that protects it?_

If there is one global invariant, then there should be one global lock object associated with it.  If there is a separate invariant for each instance of some class, Foo, then its obvious that the lock should be a component of the same instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer just defines briefly what is object lock and class lock, but not when you should use each one.

With Object level lock you make sure that different threads cannot make something unsafe to the same instance of an object.

Class level lock ensures that different instances of an object, in differents threads, cannot access to an unsafe code block that can be static method. You can see more details [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2462228/1919228)