# Threads access on Synchronized Block/Code Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I was reading [Synchronized](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html) working. Here is the example:

```
public class Singleton{

private static volatile Singleton _instance;

public static Singleton getInstance(){
   if(_instance == null){
            synchronized(Singleton.class){
              if(_instance == null)
              _instance = new Singleton();
            }
   }
   return _instance;
}
```

Let Suppose two Thread `A` and `B` are accessing `getInstance();` method, 
If thread `A` is in `synchronized` block then thread `B` will skip that block and execute next block/statement or will wait/blocked until Thread `A` leave the  `synchronized` block.

2nd What is, why is `Singleton.class` in `synchronized` parameter and when it could be `null`

and the below `Statement` is true?

> Intrinsic locks are on the object:
>
> ```
> class A
> {
>    public synchronized void method1(){...}
>    public synchronized void method2(){...}
> }
> ```
>
> If thread A is in `method1` then `threadB` cannot enter `method2` or any other synchronized method .

Comment: Deleted my initial answer.  Looks like Java has different semantics than C#, which I was translating to this situation.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2462215/141172

Comment: @EricJ. can you confirm that is it true? `If thread A is in method1 then threadB cannot enter method2 or any other synchronized method .
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Thread B will wait, until Thread A will release the lock on the synchronized object and execute the code, after it will aquire the lock on the synchronized object.

2: `Singleton.class` is the object, that represent that class. You are synchronizing on it, since your `_instance`-object is null.

```
public synchronized void method1(){...}
```

is synchronizing on the Object, on that you call that method, that means, 2 Threads will wait for each other, if you call it like this:

```
final A a = new A();
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        a.method1();
    }
}).start();
a.method1();
```

but both threads will be executed parallel, if you call it on different Objects:

```
A a = new A();
final A b = new A();
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        b.method1();
    }
}).start();
a.method1();
```

last question: right, Thread B will not enter method 2, since the synchronized method locks on the Object

Btw.

```
public synchronized void method1(){...}
```

is equivalent to:

```
public void method1(){
    synchronized(this){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Johnny why you use `final` keyword?

Comment: @NewBie without final you wouldn't be able to "see" that variable in the `Runnable`. Thats way the variable will be stored in the heap and not the stack and will be available outside the Method-Stack

Comment: and Johny as you said, `Singleton.class` is object then what is the mean of this statement? `Only important thing to note here is that if object used to lock synchronized block of code, Singleton.class in below example is null then Java synchronized block will throw a NullPointerException.` then we will face Exception each time(instance creation)? this statement is from my given link.

Comment: @NewBie no, `Singleton.class` is an object, that is representing the class. It is NOT an Object of type `Singleton`. In Java there is alway 1 Object, that is representing the class. E.g. if you would make a `static` `synchronized` method, that method would lock on that Class-Object. And it is not `null`

Comment: one another nice point. Can you give me link about Class-Object? I want to learn more how it useful and why we require it etc... or you mean about Object that used to access static-fields?

Comment: @NewBie hmmm google gave me this:) http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/reloading-objects-classes-classloaders/

Comment: it could not be null at all?

Comment: @NewBie no, it will be loaded by the classloader on start up. Normally you don't really need to worry about that object

Comment: @NewBie hmm actually I think the class is only loaded, if you use/reference the class somewhere in the code, but nvm. you shouldn't be worried about that, it is something java takes care about. That object can defenetly not be `null`

Comment: @NewBie

      To answer "... why you use final keyword?"

Any local instance variable for example the  'b' in :
<code>
class Example{
      public void m1(){
            A a = new A();
            final A b = new A();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(){  //Anonymous Thread class
                     public void run(){
                          b.method1();
                       }
             };
            t1.start();
       }
}
</code>
should be final or effectively final if accessed from anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) for documentation on the synchronized keyword.

Using `synchronized` on a method will only allow one thread at a time to access the method. All other threads will block and be queued for execution. When you use this keyword, the instance object is used as a lock to synchronize the execution. If you are calling methods on the same object only one thread can hold the lock at a time so your statement is true.

Using the `synchronized` keyword on a method can be performance-degrading, and it's recommended to use the Java concurrency API instead, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).