# Class level locking in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locking

Suppose I have a class on which I want to obtain class level lock. Do I necessarily need to have static methods inside the class to achieve the class level locking or by simply using `synchronized(MyClass.class)` will do the job without any static methods in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a class level lock in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462104/what-is-a-class-level-lock-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronizing on the `Class` object will do the trick.

Alternatively, if you want your class-level lock to not interfere with a different class-level lock on the same class, then declare a private static field to be the lock; e.g.

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final Object myLock = new Object();
    private static final Object anotherLock = new Object();
    ...
}
```

Now we have two distinct "class-level" locks for the same class.

Comment: So in that case will this piece of code written below will achieve my purpose of class level lock?

`class A
{
some code here without using static keyword in field or in any method in class A
}
class B
{
synchronized(A.class)
{
--some code here--
}
}`

Comment: @user5451270 What you are saying will work but I don't know why you want to do like that, typically class level locks for used for static methods synchronization while object locks are used for non-static methods synchronization.

Comment: @hagrawal I am not using it. I just wanted to be sure that's it.

Comment: Yes it will work.  But it strikes me as *wrong* for code `B` to synchronize on `A.class`.  That can interfere with the code of `A`.  In a sense, it breaks encapsulation for `A`.

Comment: Thanks. But how will it break the encapsulation for class A ? Sorry but I am not able to understand it fully

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReentrantLock as well:

```
private static final Lock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();  
public static void main(String... strings) {
    lock1.lock();
    //do Something
    lock1.unlock();
}
```